# How to check if T from IEnumerable<T> is IInterface?

Tags: c#, generics, types, interface, typechecking

Basically, what would be the equivalent of this but is 100% guaranteed to work?

```
 object x = new List<MyTypeWhichImplementsIInterface>();
 bool shouldBeTrue = x is IEnumerable<IInterface>;
```

From some rough testing it seems to work, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This should work in .Net 4.

Comment: @lee That's awesome :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work in C# 4, but not in prior versions.

The `is` statement takes advantage of covariance for generic type parameters, a feature added in C# 4. Prior to C# 4, the statement would be false.

Answer (score 3):

It works because the `IEnumerable<T>` is actually `IEnumerable<out T>`. Without the variance-specifier on the `<T>` it wouldn't work.

So, as long as yout interface has correct variance specifiers, and as long as 'T' at both sides satisfy the type of the variance, it's ok.

If there are no `in/out` specifiers, then the T must match exactly for the cast to succeed, and the manual check presented by CSJ is the only option left.

Answer (score 3):

```
x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>) &&
typeof(IInterface).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]);
```

Comment: This won't work right if I give you an instance of `class MyList : List<MyTypeWhichImplementsIInterface>`, or `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`

Comment: You meant `typeof(IInterface).IsAssignableFrom(...`

Comment: @dcastro: You're right, I always get that bass-ackwards.